# How can I put the next values in my #each in handlebars into the next line?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

i am having trouble using {{#each}} helper for array, as what i have seen in different tutorials when you have an array like this: (this is the array values im trying to output, this is from my main.js)

```
res.render('contact', {
        people: [
            "james",
            "peter",
            "sandrack",
            "morissa"
        ]
```

and this is my contact.handlebars:

```
{{#each people}}
<p> {{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

from the tutorials, the output must be that the names are in different lines like this:
james
peter
sandrack
morissa

but instead my output is only in one line and also without space:
[image]

can anyone please help me solve my problem, it will be a big help for me thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but, It is something you didn't send in your question...

Check every tag and "(" or "{" in your script.

It works.

```
module.exports.test = (req,res,next) => {
  res.render('test', {
    people: [
        "james",
        "peter",
        "sandrack",
        "morissa"
    ]})
}
```

View:

```
{{#each people}}
<p>{{this}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Even, for clearly understand how it works, you can use:

```
{{#each people as |name|}}
<p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```